# Дано 20 чисел, образующих последовательность. Несколько цифр, идущих подряд равны между собой. Как найти количество таких чисел?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дано 20 чисел, образующих последовательность. Несколько чисел, идущих подряд равны между собой. Как найти количество таких чисел? И сколько различных чисел есть в последовательности?

```
import random
numbers = []
k = 0
for i in range(20):
    n = random.randint(1, 10)
    numbers.append(n)
    print(n, end=', ')
print()
for i in n:
    if n[i] == n[i-1] == n[i+1]:
        k += 1
        print(k)
```

7, 5, 3, 5, 2, 2, 7, 1, 2, 6, 2, 4, 7, 2, 1, 6, 10, 7, 2, 4,
Числа идущие подряд и равны между собой: 2 (так как две двойки подряд) Различных чисел в последовательности: 8 (8 чисел, а потом повторения их же)

Comment: Вам нужно посчитать, сколько суммарно таких чисел, которые попадаются несколько раз подряд? Предоставьте, пожалуйста, пример числа и что должны для него получить в результате.

Comment: ДлЯ начала нужно определиться - речь о числах или цифрах. И исправить вопрос нужным образом.

Comment: 7, 5, 3, 5, 2, 2, 7, 1, 2, 6, 2, 4, 7, 2, 1, 6, 10, 7, 2, 4,
Числа идущие подряд и равны между собой: 2
(так как две двойки подряд)
Различных чисел в последовательности: 8
(8 чисел, а потом повторения их же)

Comment: Что выводить если подряд идут три двойки и четыре тройки? 3, 4 или 7?

Comment: три двойки + четыре тройки выводить 7

Answer (score 0):

Решение задачи:

```py
import random
numbers = [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(20)]
print(numbers)
k = 0
i = 0
while i in range(len(numbers)):
  k_ = k
  for j in range(i+1, len(numbers)):
    if numbers[i] == numbers[j]:
      k += 1
    else:
      break
  if k != k_:
    k += 1
    i += k-k_
  else:
    i += 1


print(f'Суммарная длина всех серий : {k}')
print(f'Различных элементов : {len(set(numbers))}')
```

Результат:

```
[7, 7, 1, 10, 2, 2, 7, 7, 8, 8, 2, 10, 7, 4, 4, 6, 1, 10, 8, 4]
Суммарная длина всех серий : 10
Различных элементов : 7
```

Изначально ответ был опубликован в [Python ошибка: "int object is not iterable"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1058965), т.к. там вопрос был корректно сформулирован раньше.