# Python ошибка: "int object is not iterable"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задание:

> Дано 20 чисел,которые создают последовательность. Несколько цифр
>   которые йдут подряд, равны между собой. 1)Найти  и вывести количиство
>   таких чисел. 2)Вывести сколько разных чисел есть в последовательности

Ошибка:

> ```
> for i in n: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
> ```

```
import random
numbers = []
k = 0
for i in range(20):
    n = random.randint(1, 20)
    numbers.append(n)
    print(n, end=',')
print()
for i in n:
    if n[i] == n[i-1] == n[i+1]:
        k += 1
        print(k)
```

Comment: Кроме этого ошибки есть

Comment: @SKIP если не трудно то подскажи пожалуйста

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример входных данных и результата для них. Опишите задачу, что она должна делать. Аналогичный код был в вопросе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1058825, где также остался без ответа, поскольку вопрос сформулирован не полностью. Если сможете правильно сформулировать вопрос, чтобы он был понятен - сможете получить ответ

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Дано 20 чисел, образующих последовательность. Несколько цифр, идущих подряд равны между собой. Как найти количество таких чисел?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1058825/%d0%94%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be-20-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80-%d0%b8%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4-%d1%80%

Comment: @SKIP, зачем объявлять тревогу, если ответ сначала был дан здесь, а не в той теме?) Обычно тревоги объявляют, если повторно задают вопрос, на который уже был ответ. Когда задавался этот вопрос, в той теме ответа ещё не было

Comment: @Евгений Тоесть пусть будут на сайте 2 одинаковых вопроса с 2 одинаковыми ответами?

Comment: @SKIP тоже верно . _.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение задачи:

```py
import random
numbers = [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(20)]
print(numbers)
k = 0
i = 0
while i in range(len(numbers)):
  k_ = k
  for j in range(i+1, len(numbers)):
    if numbers[i] == numbers[j]:
      k += 1
    else:
      break
  if k != k_:
    k += 1
    i += k-k_
  else:
    i += 1


print(f'Суммарная длина всех серий : {k}')
print(f'Различных элементов : {len(set(numbers))}')
```

Результат:

```
[7, 7, 1, 10, 2, 2, 7, 7, 8, 8, 2, 10, 7, 4, 4, 6, 1, 10, 8, 4]
Суммарная длина всех серий : 10
Различных элементов : 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Немного не понимаю, что вам надо, но попытался следовать Вашему коду

```
import random
numbers = []
k = 0
for i in range(20):
    n = random.randint(1, 20)
    numbers.append(n)
    print(n, end=',')

for i in range(len(numbers)):
    try:
        if numbers[i] == numbers[i-1] == numbers[i+1]:
            k += 1
    except IndexError:
        pass

print("\n" + str(k))
```

Comment: Не ошибка, но всё-таки, вдруг полезно будет ;) Если левая граница у `range` - ноль, её можно не указывать. Т.е. вместо `range(0, len(numbers))` можно писать `range(len(numbers))`

Comment: @Евгений На мое мнение так легче читать, но поправил

Comment: @SKIP задачу добавил(

Comment: @nikitahelp я поправил ваш код, что-то еще не понятно в задаче?